# How do we iterate through muliple list and call a setter method using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 lists.

```
List<Email> emailList emailList = getEmails();
List<FileData> fileList = getFileList();
```

```
public class Email {

    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Set<Permissions>;

    //getter and setter
}
```

```
public class Permissions {

    private String permissionType;
    private String level;

    //getter and setter
}
```

```
public class FileData {

    private String email;
    private String type;

    //getter and setter
}
```

I need to iterate through the list match the email from both list and call setPermissionType() method and if there is no match with the Email it needs to throw NotFoundException. How can we do this with Java streams?

The logic I have at the moment is.

```
for (final FileData fileData: fileList ) {
    Email email= emailDao.findByEmail(fileData.getEmail()); //throws NotFoundException
    final Set<Permissions> permissions = email.getPermissions();
    permissions.removeIf(p -> p.getPermissionType() == fileData.getType());
    email.setPermissions(permissions);
}
```

In the above logic I'm making DB calls in a for loop. I need to avoid that by using IN clause.

```
List<String> emailStringList = fileList.stream()
                                       .map(file -> Objects.toString(file.getEmail()))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Email> emailList= emailDao.findByEmailIn(emailStringList);
```

Comment: The logic you have now seems to be clean and readable. Why convert it to Java streams?

Comment: You set the Permissions with "contactPermissions" shouldn't it be just "permissions"?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Does the streams makes this more complex? I just want to know if there is better solution than what I have.

Comment: @Nordiii I have corrected it now. Thanks.

Comment: Streams are usually not a good solution for making changes, and are really bad for checked exceptions. They certainly shouldn't be used just because they are new.

Comment: You can iterate easily on Collections of collections using Stream's flatmap function.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm making a DB call in the for loop emailDao.findByEmail(). If I have the List<Email> using IN clause emailDao.findByEmailIn() it will be 1 call to the DB. Then I will have 2 lists like mentioned above. I need to filter from 2 lists.

Comment: sidebar: use `String.equals` (not ==) to compare Strings

Comment: First, using a list is not efficient. A database call where you have an index may actually be faster. You can preload the emails into a `HashSet` (remember to override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods!). Or hashmap by email address.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to remove emailDao.findByEmail() inside a loop, this costs you a huge cost and technical debt

1. First of all, create a list of emails

   `List<String> emailIds = fileList.stream().map(fileData->FileData::getEmail).collect(Collectors.toList());`
2. Create a new method findByEmails(List emails) to find by multiple emails.

   `List<Email> emails = emailDao.findByEmails(emailIds);`
3. I think, Something like this would work

   `emails.forEach(email-> 
    email.setPermissions(email.getPermissions().stream().fiter(permission -> !permission.getType().equals(fileList.stream().filter(file-> file.getEmail().equals(email.getEmail()).findFirst().orElse(new Permission())).getType()))))`

Also, I think this will eliminate the NotFoundException as we're iterating only on the already existing emails.